# Object in jquery using json response

Tags: php, jquery, json, javascript-objects

I want to create an object in jquery using a json response that is return from my controller

```
var cellContents = {'29-08-2018': '20','18-08-2018': '60'};
```

This is the desired format that i want and below given is my json response

```
{"status":1,"result":[{"followup_datee":"17-08-2018","date":[{"fcount":"1"}]},{"followup_datee":"18-08-2018","date":[{"fcount":"1"}]}]}
```

i tried some code to make the format that i want but it failed this is the code that i tried

```
var arr2 = [];
      //var cellContents = JSON.parse(data.result);

      for(var i=0; i<data.result.length; i++){
        var arr = [];
        for(var j=0; j<data.result[i].date.length; j++)
        { 
        arr.push(parseInt(data.result[i].date[j].fcount));
        } 
        var test = [data.result[i].followup_datee];
        arr2.push(test.concat(arr));
        } 
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(arr2);
      console.log(jsonString);
```

after i tried this code i got some response in the console like this

```
[["17-08-2018",1],["18-08-2018",1]]
```

This is the controller that i am using in php

```
 public function getLeadcount()
{
    $status = 1;
    $arr = [];
    $sess = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $result = $this->mdl_lead_registration->getLeaddate($sess);
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        $status = 1;
        foreach($result as $res)
        {
            $res->{'date'} = '';
            $res->date = $this->mdl_lead_registration->getLeadcount($sess,$res->followup_datee);
        }

    }

   echo json_encode(array("status" => $status,"result" => $result));
}
```

I think you all understand my problem . Any sort of help is appreciable.

Comment: Please give an example - what are you get from the server, what's the js result, and what's the result you want.

Comment: I want result like this {'17-08-2018': '1','18-08-2018': '1'} but i am getting like this [["17-08-2018",1],["18-08-2018",1]]

Comment: Why your `date` property is an array? Do you want result like `{'17-08-2018': [1],'18-08-2018': [1]}`?

Comment: i dont want any array format in my result i want date as my key and count as my value

Comment: But you've array of `date`s! Dio you want to get the sum of them?

Comment: no actually this my json response {"status":1,"result":[{"followup_datee":"17-08-2018","date":[{"fcount":"1"}]},{"followup_datee":"18-08-2018","date":[{"fcount":"1"}]}]} all i want is that i want to convert this to {'17-08-2018': '1','18-08-2018': '1'} this format

Comment: Yes! See that any `followup_datee` has an array of `date`s! Why?

Comment: ok that is because first i take all the dates and then only i take the data belogs to each of the date

Comment: And you want to include in the object only the first date?

Comment: yes first date and its data then next...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```js
var data = {"status":1,"result":[{"followup_datee":"17-08-2018","date":[{"fcount":"1"}]},{"followup_datee":"18-08-2018","date":[{"fcount":"1"}]}]};

var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++){
  obj[data.result[i].followup_datee] = parseInt(data.result[i].date[0].fcount);
  // Here you change the property.
  // In js you can access to an object's property like an array,
  // see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors.

  // If you want to use the count as a string, use instead:
  // obj[data.result[i].followup_datee] = data.result[i].date[0].fcount;
}

console.log(obj);
```